# Find sitemap of newworldencyclopedia.org

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have no luck finding the sitemap of https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org.

It is not here: https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/robots.txt

I tried these:

- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap.xml
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap.txt
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap.php
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap.xml.gz
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap1.xml
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap_index.xml
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemap-index.xml
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemapindex.xml
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/rss.xml
- https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/sitemaps/

Searching google for `site:newworldencyclopedia.org filetype:xml` doesn't give me anything either.

Any idea where I can find it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about locating a sitemap on some random site.

Comment: They may not have a sitemap.  In any case, if you want an answer to this question you should be asking them.